# Label difference between bar and line plot matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I have this `dataframe`:

```
    date         Ta
0   2018-01-01  -22.8
1   2018-01-02  -14.2
2   2018-01-03  -10.7
3   2018-01-04  -13.5
4   2018-01-05  -10.6
5   2018-01-06  -10.2
6   2018-01-07  -2.3
7   2018-01-08  0.5
8   2018-01-09  3.1
9   2018-01-10  4.7
```

If I plot this data as a bar plot, I am able to get the label (for the legend) because the type is `matplotlib.container.BarContainer`, however, when I plot it as a line, I can't get the label because it is a `list` type.

```
type(ax2.bar(ex['date'],ex['Ta'],color='purple',label='Ta'))
>>> matplotlib.container.BarContainer

ax2.bar(ex['date'],ex['Ta'],color='purple',label='Ta').get_label()
>>>'Ta'



type(ax2.plot(ex['date'],ex['Ta'],color='purple',label='Ta'))
>>> list

type(ax2.plot(ex['date'],ex['Ta'],color='purple',label='Ta')).get_label()
>>> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-c9c7cacb12b8> in <module>
----> 1 type(ax2.plot(ex['date'],ex['Ta'],color='purple',label='Ta')).get_label()

AttributeError: type object 'list' has no attribute 'get_label
```

Why is that?

Comment: `plot` returns a list. You need to use `get_label()` on the contents of the list

Comment: Thanks, I did that and it worked. `ax2.plot(ex['date'],ex['Ta'],color='purple',label='Ta')[0].get_label()`